# Why CrystalDiskInfo says "caution" on my disk and AIDA64 does not?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a WD disk. It seemed to worked without problems; but I noticed CrystalDiskInfo showing "CAUTION" on it:

[image: CrystalDiskInfo report on the suspicious disk]

AIDA64 and some other utilities also show no errors on the suspicious disk:

```
AIDA64 Extreme

Version     AIDA64 v5.60.3700
Benchmark Module    4.1.643-x32
Homepage    http://www.aida64.com/
Report Type     Quick Report [ TRIAL VERSION ]
Computer    BIG
Generator   andr
Operating System    Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1.7601.19135 (Win7 RTM)  
Date    2016-02-23
Time    17:55


SMART
---

[ WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 (WD-WMC301319847) ]

ID      Attribute Description   Threshold   Value   Worst   Data    Status
01      Raw Read Error Rate     51      200     200     4025    OK: Value is normal  
03      Spinup Time     21      176     172     4158    OK: Value is normal  
04      Start/Stop Count    0   100     100     282     OK: Always passes
05      Reallocated Sector Count    140     200     200     0   OK: Value is normal  
07      Seek Error Rate     0   100     253     0   OK: Always passes
09      Power-On Time Count     0   77      77      16937   OK: Always passes
0A      Spinup Retry Count      0   100     100     0   OK: Always passes
0B      Calibration Retry Count     0   100     100     0   OK: Always passes
0C      Power Cycle Count   0   100     100     271     OK: Always passes
C0      Power-Off Retract Count     0   200     200     92      OK: Always passes
C1      Load/Unload Cycle Count     0   200     200     189     OK: Always passes
C2      Temperature     0   119     103     28      OK: Always passes
C4      Reallocation Event Count    0   200     200     0   OK: Always passes
C5      Current Pending Sector Count    0   200     200     14      OK: Always passes
C6      Offline Uncorrectable Sector Count      0   100     253     0   OK: Always passes
C7      Ultra ATA CRC Error Rate    0   200     200     0   OK: Always passes
C8      Write Error Rate    0   100     253     0   OK: Always passes
```

I have another disk which is a twin of the problematic one. CrystalDiskInfo shows it as "GOOD". The only following parameters are different for it:

- Spin-Up Time
- Seek Error Rate
- Power-On Hours
- Temperature
- Write Error Rate
- raw value of the item C5. On the "Caution" disk it is 0xE (14); On the "Good" disk it is 0

[image: CrystalDiskInfo report on the "GOOD" disk]

What is the status of the suspicious disk? Is the risk of its failing higher than that of its twin? Why?

Comment: You missed the raw value of the item C5. On the "Caution" disk it is 0xE (14); On the "Good" disk it is 0.

Comment: Because “OK: Always passes”. ;) It simply ignores the value.